# How do i make a python code (3.4.3) that can take a compressed file and recreate the full text?

Tags: python, python-3.4, compression

So the task was to compress a .txt file which i did here is the code for that

```
import gzip
import shutil

with open('dictionary.txt', 'rb') as f_input, gzip.open('dictionary.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_output:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_input, f_output)
```

Now my task is to open that compressed file and and recreate the full text, including punctuation and capitalization.

Here is what i got at the moment but it's not quite working :/ feel like somethings very wrong with it.

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('dictionary.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

- If anyone could see why this isn't working that would be very appreciated. 
  I just need to open a compressed file and recreate the full text.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrmZW.jpg)
- The image below is what's in the compressed file and the .txt file

Comment: not working how exactly?

Comment: any error messages? expected output compared to actual?

Comment: is the .gz file correct when you open it with an archiver?

Comment: It's just not recreating the full text it just doesn't do anything, no errors . I think maybe the file location could be wrong so imma try that

Comment: do you get any error messages? you have to run that from a console to see the errors. Yes, different working directory could be the issue.

Comment: stupid question: have you tried `print(file_content)` ?

Comment: I feel stupid now xD that worked, printing the file content was it!